# ant : macro for exec that echoes command it executes, including arguments

Tags: ant, arguments, exec, echo

Currently I do this:

```
  <echo message="cd ${build.dir}/scripts ; ./update.sh ${arg1} ${arg2} ${arg3} ${arg4} ${arg5} ${arg6} ; cd -" />
  <exec dir="${build.dir}/scripts"
        executable="./update.sh"
        resultproperty="update.result" >
    <arg value="${arg1}"/>
    <arg value="${arg2}"/>
    <arg value="${arg3}"/>
    <arg value="${arg4}"/>
    <arg value="${arg5}"/>
    <arg value="${arg6}"/>
  </exec>
```

The `echo` affords me some ease of what-went-wrong. However, the echo statement needs to be updated in tandem with the exec statement's arguments, otherwise this debug output is a mismatch.

What I would like to be able to do is:

```
<execWithEcho dir="${build.dir}/scripts"
      executable="./update.sh"
      resultproperty="update.result" >
  <arg value="${arg1}"/>
  <arg value="${arg2}"/>
  <arg value="${arg3}"/>
  <arg value="${arg4}"/>
  <arg value="${arg5}"/>
  <arg value="${arg6}"/>
</exec>
```

Which results in the same as above.

Where `execWithEcho` would be a macro defined as such:

```
<macrodef name="execWithEcho">
  <attribute name="attr.dir"
             description="Directory to run exec in."/>
  <attribute name="attr.executable"
             description="The executable target."/>
  <attribute name="attr.resultProperty"
             description="The property to set the retern value of the target executable/"/>
  <sequential>
    <echo message="//TODO implement echo in execWithEcho"/>
    <exec dir="@{attr.dir}"
          executable="@{attr.executable}"
          resultProperty="@{attr.resultProperty}">
          <!-- args go here -->
    </exec>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

What I am unsure of here is how to iterate over all of the child `<arg />` elements that are passed in; concatenating them into a single string, in a manner required for the echo statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See Mark's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10304234/54506

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to put the echo in the update.sh than ant?